# compare CoreML vs SKLearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, coreml

So, it is a simple script to compare the running time between a normal sklearn model and converted CoreML model, however, the error shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[119], line 23
     20 model_sklearn.fit(X_train, y_train)
     22 # Convert scikit-learn model to Core ML
---> 23 coreml_model = skl_converter.convert(model_sklearn)
     25 # Load the Core ML model
     26 coreml_model = cml.models.MLModel(coreml_model)

File ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/developer/pre-production/stock-trader/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/sklearn/_converter.py:148, in convert(sk_obj, input_features, output_feature_names)
    144 from ...models import MLModel
    145 # NOTE: Providing user-defined class labels will be enabled when
    146 # several issues with the ordering of the classes are worked out.  For now,
    147 # to use custom class labels, directly import the internal function below.
--> 148 from ._converter_internal import _convert_sklearn_model
    150 spec = _convert_sklearn_model(
    151     sk_obj, input_features, output_feature_names, class_labels=None
    152 )
    154 model = MLModel(spec)

File ~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/developer/pre-production/stock-trader/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/coremltools/converters/sklearn/_converter_internal.py:24
     19     from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline as sk_Pipeline
     21 from collections import namedtuple as _namedtuple
---> 24 from . import (_SVC, _SVR, _decision_tree_classifier, _decision_tree_regressor,
     25                _dict_vectorizer, _gradient_boosting_classifier,
...
   (...)
     36         Protobuf representation of the model
     37     """

NameError: name '_tree' is not defined
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

Python Script:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import coremltools as cml
import coremltools.converters.sklearn as skl_converter
import time

# Load the Boston Housing dataset
boston = pd.read_csv('./jupyter_data/housing.csv')
X =boston.drop(columns = {'MEDV'})
y = boston.MEDV

# Split the dataset into training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Train a scikit-learn linear regression model
model_sklearn = LinearRegression()
model_sklearn.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Convert scikit-learn model to Core ML
coreml_model = skl_converter.convert(model_sklearn)
```

Very wierd that I have updated all packages but still saw this `_tree not defined` error. Anyone knows what happens?

Please replace the dataset with anything you have.